How to add additional files to an existing snap installation?
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Rev. B 4GB. I installed OS 64-bit from 2024-11-19 with Desktop. Afterwards I installed snapd and the Snap Store app.
From there I've installed noson (while I don't like Sonos app).
On an Ubuntu 20.04 installation on a different Laptop noson works fine. On the Raspi it won't work. It aborted with an error like this:
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled. 

My guess! The lib "libqxcb-glx-integration.so" in the directory /snap/noson/631/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations is missing. This is a major difference from the running version of noson on Ubuntu! The library I've found, my problem now is, snap installation are in a special read-only /dev/loopX filesystem! Now my question is: How can I make the filesystem read writable and copy the missing lib there? I've read many blogs and snap howto's, but I found nothing.

snap packages are built as a squashfs or READ ONLY file-system that can be mounted and used, but not changed. To modify it, you make a new snap package (ie. create a new squashfs).  That is intentional, as it prevents corruption.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/10i6m19/i_figured_out_how_to_modify_installed_snaps/  is the best you will find

and do read the last part: you need to redo it after every update so create a script so you have not have to do it manually every time.

Let the snap maintainer know about the missing file. If they update the snap, you can have that update in a couple hours.

@Rinzwind, thank you for your answer! I was able to patch the snap as you mentioned! Unfortunately this don't solve my problem!
